# Webpack-cli init can't add an entry point

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

I'm running `npx webpack-cli init`.

The first question is `will your application have multiple bundles?  No`

Then the next question: `Which will be your application entry point?` the prompt is there but I can't type anything in, enter does not work it just appears that iTerm is frozen. I tried this in both bash and zsh but I haven't encountered something like this before.

Comment: Yep seeing the same... tried it with stock macOS Terminal also.